# How to download data of bar chart from shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting error file, while downloading data of bar chart rendered in shiny UI.
There is a download button just below the chart. While click on the 'Download data' button, data should be downloaded into csv format.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ECharts2Shiny)

dat <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 4, 6))
names(dat) <- c("Type-A", "Type-B")
row.names(dat) <- c("Time-1", "Time-2", "Time-3")

ui <- fluidpage( loadEChartsLibrary(),
tags$div(id="test", style="width:50%;height:400px;"),
deliverChart(div_id = "test"), downloadButton("test", "Download Data"))

server <-  function(input, output) {
renderBarChart(div_id = "test", grid_left = '1%', direction = "vertical",               
data = dat)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to download the data of that bar chart in ".csv" format.
Can anyone help me out to correct the code?

Thank you.

Comment: What is an *"error file"*? If you are getting an *error* trying to download the *file*, can you include the exact text of the error?

Comment: Thank you r@evans for quick response to this querry.

Comment: I am not getting the error but the outcome of the 'DownloadData' button is make open to another r script in which some html code written within it.

Comment: I am saving the file by naming it 'abc' on desktop. Then when I run this file it opened up in a r' script by showing some html or java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot use the same "renderTable" server output for all of your UI inputs. AKA, you need to make a separate input and output for your image in the form of a downloadable file. Here is an example of what I did to download a .csv file:

```
output$downloadData <- reactive({
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste("ProcessedData-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
},
content = function(file) {
  write.csv(DataTable, file)
}
)
```

Therefore in your download button you would replace "test" with "downloadData" so that it connects to a new server output. Notice that I am creating the file here with write.csv, but not actually writing to any disk just generating the file and passing it into the downloadData output for users to trigger and then save to their own disk when they hit the downloadData input button. You are trying to save a picture so I suggest trying something along the lines of generating an image file inside of the content call. Recall that you can save images as objects:

```
#up in the UI somewhere
ui <- fluidpage(loadEChartsLibrary(),
tags$div(id="test", style="width:50%;height:400px;"),
deliverChart(div_id = "test"), downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data"))  

server <-  function(input, output) {
output$test <- renderBarChart(div_id = "test", grid_left = '1%', direction = "vertical",               
data = dat)

output$downloadData <- reactive({
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste("Image.png", sep="") #just the file name you want to have as default
},
content = function(file) {
  write.csv(DataTable, file)
)
}
```

I don't have your actual code so this may not work as a plug and play solution, but I believe this is the right direction.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the effort you made here.

Comment: But, I am not able to download the data behind the chart in excel / .csv format.

Comment: When I am clicking on the download button in shiny U, it asks me to save a file. But getting no option .csv to save as csv file.

Comment: I think you have to run the shinyApp in the browser and not in the RStudio-viewer.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your original question I thought you wanted to download the image. I have edited the code to write a csv file. Please update me with what you are trying for trouble shooting / post more of your original code if possible.